# Delete Words w/Upper And Lowercase Letters or Only Lowercase Letters

Tags: sql, ms-access, uppercase, lowercase

**Objective:** I have an Access table with a column Item_Desc. I want this column to only contain the brand names of clothing. The brand names are always written in ALL CAPS, e.g., "RALPH LAUREN".

**Problem:** The Item_Desc column is populated with both brand names and type of article of clothing (and color and etc.). Thus, the Item_Desc column may contain, for example, "RALPH LAUREN" (good) or possibly "RALPH LAUREN Coat black" (bad).

**Question:** Is there a query I can run that will delete the words from Item_Desc that either: 1) Begin with an uppercase letter followed by lowercase letters (e.g., "Coat"), or 2) Are written solely in lowercase (e.g., "black").

Thus, "RALPH LAUREN Coat black" would end up as just "RALPH LAUREN" in the Item_Desc column.

My table name is "Brand".

Lastly, I have no control over the report generated, so I unfortunately can't import Brand, Style, and Color into separate columns to begin with (I don't think!).

Comment: Did you want to do this with only basic Access SQL, meaning a query which does not rely on a custom VBA function?  I'm skeptical about whether this is a reasonable task for plain Access SQL.

Comment: I would be just fine with using VBA as well!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a VBA function based on a regular expression to accomplish your goal.

Here is one such function tested in the Immediate window with your sample inputs:

```vb
? OnlyUpperCaseWords("RALPH LAUREN")
RALPH LAUREN
? OnlyUpperCaseWords("RALPH LAUREN Coat black")
RALPH LAUREN
```

You could use that function in an `UPDATE` query to change your stored *Item_Desc* values:

```sql
UPDATE Brand AS b
SET b.Item_Desc = OnlyUpperCaseWords(b.Item_Desc)
WHERE b.Item_Desc Is Not Null;
```

This is the function ...

```vb
Public Function OnlyUpperCaseWords(ByVal strSource As String) As String
    Static re As Object

    If re Is Nothing Then
        Set re = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
        re.Global = True
        re.IgnoreCase = False
        re.Pattern = "\s*\b[A-Za-z]*[a-z]+[A-Za-z]*\b\s*"
    End If
    'OnlyUpperCaseWords = re.Replace(strSource, vbNullString)
    OnlyUpperCaseWords = Trim(re.Replace(strSource, " "))
End Function
```

Comment: HansUp, thank you much for your response. So I saved the function in VBA as OnlyUpperCaseWords, and I saved the query in Access. I tried running the query, and it returned an error message: "Undefined function 'OnlyUpperCaseWords' in expression". Got any ideas how to resolve this? From your immediate window, I can see you wrote it perfectly. I am just trying to figure out what I am doing wrong!

Comment: The function is saved as a module in the Access database itself, that contains table Brand.

Comment: What is the name you gave to the module?  If you named the module *OnlyUpperCaseWords* ... the same as the function ... change it to something else ... *modOnlyUpperCaseWords* would work.

Comment: Wow...you are good...brilliant. That worked perfectly, and I thank you very much for the help, HansUp!

Comment: I realized later that `OnlyUpperCaseWords("ONE two THREE")` would return *"ONETHREE"*, so revised it to return *"ONE THREE"* from that input.